# why typescript doesn't raise an error 'TS2339: Property a does not exist on type A '?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [Constrained Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins), when i try to access a non-defined property `a` in my `test()` function, no error raised, it should raise an error `TS2339: Property  a  does not exist on type  A`, why not happen?

```
export function withBindable<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(BaseType: T) {
    return class extends BaseType {
        public mixin = 1;
    };
}

class Base{
    public b = 2;
}

class A extends withBindable(Base){
    public test(){
        this.mixin = 2; // OK
        this.b = 3; // OK
        this.a = 2; // should raise an error, but no error raised, tsc will compile this code successfully, and typeof this.a is any 
    }
}
```

Comment: @jcalz  changing constraint from `T extends new (...args: any[]) => any` to `T extends new (...args: any[]) => object` does the trick, and resolve my problem. but `T extends new (...args: any[]) => unknown` does not work, it will raise an new error that appear from here `extends BaseType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#33943](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39943) but it was never classified as a bug, design limitation, or intentional choice.  In that issue it is hypothesized that this seems to be a problem when the base constructor's [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) has an instance type of [the unsound `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Assuming that is so, you can rectify the problem by replacing `any` with [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) (or possibly another sound supertype like `{}`):

```
export function withBindable<T extends new (...args: any[]) => object>(BaseType: T) {
    return class extends BaseType {
        public mixin = 1;
    };
}

class Base{
    public b = 2;
}

class A extends withBindable(Base){
    public test(){
        this.mixin = 2; // OK
        this.b = 3; // OK
        this.a = 2; // error, as expected
    }
}
```

Still, the current behavior seems undesirable, so it would be nice if the issue had an official diagnosis.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwO6YwAWAQpigCYCGARgDbAA8AKnKDMJQM5wrB5wAFADpRVKAHMuALjhUUATwDaAXQCUcALwA+OBBoArYBm2CSVLsGYKwwWcw0BvAFBw3cKMBhIouNHQsedk4KHnNLa1s4F3dYuDAkekw0OABbTBByLTgARgBuV3cAXwKi52d-QLhw4GjCtwSklJpsgCZS8squHgBBNhAObnxCUnJqemAzC2AnevjEumS4Di4YQVm492JMLmF0zNxNOHa4AHpTuAB5AGk52O3dlqOAZjyzi5u7raId4So2t7nNhQKDQOZlIpAA_)